# Iterate dataframe in pandas looking for a string and generate new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
      import pandas as pd
      df = pd.DataFrame({'Id_Sensor': [1, 2, 3, 4],'Old_Column': ['P55X', 'MEC8901', 'P58Y', 'M59X']})

      print(df)

        Id_Sensor   Old_Column
           1           P55X
           2           MEC8901
           3           P58Y
           4           M59X
```

I need to create a new column on this dataframe. If the first letter is P, the column should receive 'computer_typeA'. If the first three letters are MEC the column should receive 'computer_typeB'

I tried to do the following:

```
        #This code segment is incorrect
        for i in range(0, len(df)):

          if(df['Old_Column'].iloc[i][:1] == 'P'):
               df['New_Column'].iloc[i] == 'computer_typeA'

         elif(df['Old_Column'].iloc[i][:3] == 'MEC'):
               df['New_Column'].iloc[i] == 'computer_typeB'

         else:
               df['New_Column'].iloc[i] == 'computer_other'
```

The answer is incorrect:

```
      print(df)
        Id_Sensor   Old_Column  New_Column
           1           P55X       Nan
           2          MEC8901     Nan
           3           P58Y       Nan
           4           M59X       Nan
```

I would like the answer to be like this:

```
        Id_Sensor   Old_Column       New_Column
           1           P55X       computer_typeA
           2          MEC8901     computer_typeB
           3           P58Y       computer_typeA
           4           M59X       computer_other
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple code should do the work:

```
df["New_Column"] = "computer_other"

df.loc[df.Old_Column.apply(lambda x: x[0] == "P"), "New_Column"] = "computer_typeA"

df.loc[df.Old_Column.apply(lambda x: x[:3] == "MEC"), "New_Column"] = "computer_typeB"
```

Note: The reason of the initial declaration of `New_Column` as `computer_other` is to simplify the process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, if you found the answer useful, please upvote the answer and click on the tick that is next to the answer if the answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Please avoid using ```apply(...)```: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for conditional statements:

```
cond1 = df.Old_Column.str.startswith('P')
cond2 = df.Old_Column.str.startswith('MEC')
condlist = [cond1,cond2]
choicelist = ['computer_typeA', 'computer_typeB']
df['New Column'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist)
df['New Column'] = df['New Column'].replace('0','computer_other')

   Id_Sensor    Old_Column  New Column
0   1   P55X    computer_typeA
1   2   MEC8901 computer_typeB
2   3   P58Y    computer_typeA
3   4   M59X    computer_other
```